# Azure Function Failures and warnings

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am developing function app with timmer trigger and binding and how to check failures while running the function app

Comment: @WaAzure086- If you function app is hosted on azure you can refer to the monitor section of the function as [shown here](https://i.imgur.com/cKZkq8N.png). The monitor section will help with the list of successful invocations and failure count as well. you can select any one invocation to see complete end-to-end function trigger logs. Alternatively, you can use [log stream](https://i.imgur.com/V17eo1Z.png) option(under monitoring) from the portal to see live streaming of function logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*After developing the Function App you need to enable the Application Insights and in the Azure portal on your function app to your left side pane yo can see monitoring alerts.*

*In that monitoring Alerts you can diagnose the failures and warning if there is any when you are trying to run the function app.*

[image]